# Number of states of a simple system

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am trying working on a problem in which there are two energy states $E_{1}<E_{2}$, and three different (i.e. distinguishable) particles.

I cannot decide if the order of the particles matters. If it doesn't, then there are 8 states. If order does matter, there are 24. My problem is not knowing the logic necessary to make the decision.

How many states does this system have? Is it ambiguous, given the information here, or is it definitely 8 or definitely 24?

Comment: What do you mean by "order"?

Comment: @user44816 Which order? You have the following variants: one particle on the state $E_2$ and two on $E_1$, which makes 3 possibilities, one particle on $E_1$ and two on $E_2$, so, three more possibilities, and all three particles either on $E_1$, or on $E_2$. In all, 8. Since no additional quantum numbers are given, when two or three particles are placed on the same state, there is no *order* to distinguish between them. Their type-of-particle is enough distinction.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  what's you problem whether they are fermions or bosons, once you are told the particles are distinguishable?

Comment: What I mean by order is this: Call these particles A,B, & C. there is a state in which all three of them have energy $E_{1}$. If we write this down, we might have a level representing $E_{1}$ and on that level write "A,B,C". A different order (i.e. way of writing this) would be to have, on $E_{1}$, "A,C,B". Is this a physically different state?

Comment: The particles are given as "different particles". They are intentionally not labeled as fermions or bosons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to specify what ensemble you are working in. in case of microcanonical ensemble (total energy fixed). no. of microstates will be decided by no. of different ways total energy can be E.then as only two energies are possible . let n1 particle are in state e1 n2 in state e2 with constraint that n1+n2=3 and n1*E1+n2*E2=E. total no. of microstates will be (3!/(n1)!*(n2)!).